# 2010 - Email workflow issues

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

I'm currently having issues with my email workflow and would like to get it double checked to make sure I'm understanding everything right.

My goal is this:

1. When a person enters their email in Email and the SUID field is blank, it will send a series of emails. It will send off one email immediately, then pause for a time, then send another, then pause again, and a send a final email.
2. Anytime during this workflow, if the SUID field is not empty, it should stop the workflow and not send anymore emails.

Here is how I have it set up:
[image: workflow]

The problem I'm having is the emails are still being sent after an item is edited to fill in the SUID field. My workflow is set to trigger when an item is created and when an item is changed.

Am I missing a setting? Or is that I'm not understanding how this workflow should be set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `pause` and before sending the next email you can check if `SUID` is empty of not.

If not empty then Stop the Workflow

Else Send Email

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2010, do you what action I need to use for this? I apologize as I am a beginner.

Comment: Its only the condition you need to add before `then Email CurrentItem:Student Email`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but I'm still having problems with the emails. [This is the modified workflow](http://i.imgur.com/TalBkiY.jpg), but it's still sending out all the emails.

Comment: Not correct. The If CurrentItem:SUID is empty should be after the Pause.